# How did hackers manage to create a new user while "allow user registration" is set to "NO"?

Tags: joomla-3.x, security, registration, hacked

Recently I find a new user is created on my 3.6.0 site and put into "administrator" group, but the "Allow User Registration" option is set to "NO", though the "enabled" and "Activated" status are both unchecked.

I upgraded Joomla to the latest 3.6.4, then I tried to delete the user, but I was lead to a 404 page saying the page isn't working.

I know Joomla's user registration system is often used to inject malicious files so I turn it off. How did this hacker manage to get by it? And does this mean he some how has compromised my super user account?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The main reason for 3.6.4 update was exactly what happened to you!

Security Bulletin [[20161001] - Core - Account Creation](https://developer.joomla.org/security-centre/659-20161001-core-account-creation.html) states
"Inadequate checks allows for users to register on a site when registration has been disabled."

Then, additional vulnerability which was fixed by 3.6.4 was [[20161002] - Core - Elevated Privileges](https://developer.joomla.org/security-centre/660-20161002-core-elevated-privileges.html) "Incorrect use of unfiltered data allows for users to register on a site with elevated privileges."

Now, just **how did hackers manage to create new user** while “allow user registration” is set to “NO”, you can find in Sucuri's blog '[Details on the Privilege Escalation Vulnerability in Joomla](https://blog.sucuri.net/2016/10/details-on-the-privilege-escalation-vulnerability-in-joomla.html)'.
It is very interesting read, to say at least, and pretty technical, so quite imposible to duplicate here...

What is most frightening about this vulnerability is that it not only allows hacker to create an account even when account registration is disabled, but also changes the administrator’s username, password, and email address!

**Additional reads on issues with registration:**

- '[Users registering without a registration form being published](https://vel.joomla.org/articles/1730-users-registering-without-a-registration-form-being-published)' at Joomla VEL (Vulnerable Extensions List) site, which explains it and have a few recommendations how to avoid it.
- Similar question here on JSE: '[How to stop (fake) users from registering on my website?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/14047/how-to-stop-fake-users-from-registering-on-my-website)'
- Official document on [Setting user registration policy](https://docs.joomla.org/Setting_user_registration_policy) at Joomla Documentations site.

**So, it is crucial to update your Joomlas to 3.6.4 ASAP!**

Comment: Thanks! It is a little ironic that joomla sites are extremely vulnerable every time a new update is published..

Comment: It is not ironic, but expected!. That is why they stopped publishing details about vilnerability until they issue the patch for it. But, as usuall, hackers don't sleep and can't wait to explore the holes in unprotected sites. Good read about latest vulnerability and general security can be found in Sucuri's article 'Joomla Exploits in the Wild Against CVE-2016-8870 and CVE-2016-8869' at https://blog.sucuri.net/2016/10/joomla-mass-exploits-privilege-vulnerability.html

Comment: @shenkwen - Whenever a security vulnerability is found, a patch is normally released within a couple of days. It's up to you to update your system ;) Joomla ships with a plugin that sends you email notifications when there's an update available, so may be best to use it.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible ways that the hacker has broken into your web,

I recommend you see these documents:

https://docs.joomla.org/Security

As to your question I would bet that the hacker could somehow upload a file to your website with a script that creates the user directly into the database.

With knowledge of Joomla tables and function it is relatively simple to do.

Comment: he was on J3.6.0 which was vulnerable on this exact thing - a hacker could escalate and create a super user. This is what was patched with 3.6.4 release.