# User Registration Emails? - Site Offline and Registration Disabled

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, registration

I am still getting user registration emails. But the thing is, my site is set to "OFFLINE" (so only I as Super User must login to even access the frontend) and I have User Registration set to "No".

How are people still registering on my site?

I don't even have a login/registration module published on the frontend.

I am confused as to how I am getting user registration emails?

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: What joomla version do you have? Do you have any other component installed, that is able to override joomla registration process?

Comment: Is this site upgraded to 3.6.4? all version before allow to register users even if turned off.

Comment: As @jdog pointed, this should not be possible in newest 3.6.4

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice document [Users registering without a registration form being published](https://vel.joomla.org/articles/1730-users-registering-without-a-registration-form-being-published) at Joomla VEL (Vulnerable Extensions List) site, which explains it and have a few recommendations how to avoid it.

There are few very good answers to similar question here on JSE: [How to stop (fake) users from registering on my website?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/14047/how-to-stop-fake-users-from-registering-on-my-website)

There is also official document on [Setting user registration policy](https://docs.joomla.org/Setting_user_registration_policy) at Joomla Documentations site.

Now, I don't know what to make of the fact that you have site Offline, and still get registration emails. Only thing I can think of is that your Joomla is lower than 3.6.4, but you haven't specified it.